# QrCode Open Source Library for WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, qr-code

I need to generate the Qr Code for my Windows 8 Store App.Is there any Open Source Qr Code Library which is based on Win Rt.

Answer (score 4):

I have made use of **zxing** library which is available on codeplex.

The method I wrote is as follows:

I'm making use of the `DecodeQRcode` with storage file from the camera's `CaptureFileAsync` method which returns the storage file of the `qrImgage`.

```
public async void DecodeQRCode(StorageFile file)
{
        // load a jpeg, be sure to have the Pictures Library capability in your manifest

        var data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

        // create a stream from the file
        var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var dw = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(ms);
        dw.WriteBuffer(data);
        await dw.StoreAsync();
        ms.Seek(0);

        // find out how big the image is, don't need this if you already know
        var bm = new BitmapImage();
        await bm.SetSourceAsync(ms);

        // create a writable bitmap of the right size
        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bm.PixelWidth, bm.PixelHeight);
        ms.Seek(0);

        // load the writable bitpamp from the stream
        await wb.SetSourceAsync(ms);

        var lsource = new BitmapLuminanceSource(wb);

        var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(lsource);
        var bbmp = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);

        var c = new QRCodeReader();
       Result res= c.decode(bbmp);
    }
```

While taking the image of the QR code you must make sure that you crop the image properly or else you won't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this, but [ZXing.Net](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) is....

> A library which supports decoding and generating of barcodes (like QR
>   Code, PDF 417, EAN, UPC, Aztec, Data Matrix, Codabar) within images.

and has assembles available for WindowsRT (as well as phone)

Comment: Apache 2.0 license per the site [http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/license](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/license)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ZXing.NET: https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Code for load image to get QR Code result:

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (null != file)
        {
            try
            {
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream1 = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    bitmap.SetSource(fileStream1);
                }
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream2 = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);
                    writeableBitmap.SetSource(fileStream2); IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
                    var result = reader.Decode(writeableBitmap);
                    txt1.Text = result.ToString();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

Code for get QR from camera (use the MSDN demo: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac and customized):

```
    private async void CapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            // Using Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI API to capture a photo
            CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
            Size aspectRatio = new Size(1, 1);
            dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;

            StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
            if (file != null)
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream1 = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream1);
                }
                CapturedPhoto.Source = bitmapImage;
                ResetButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                ZXing.BarcodeReader br = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
                WriteableBitmap wrb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream2 = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    wrb.SetSource(fileStream2);
                }
                var res = br.Decode(wrb);
                rootPage.NotifyUser(res.ToString(), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("No photo captured.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser(ex.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```